# php get a number of element in array after every foreach

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, codeigniter, curl

How to get a number of element in array after every foreach
Like

```
 foreach( array(20 elements in database) {
       echo $element[1];
       echo $element[2];
       echo $element[3];
       echo $element[4];
       echo $element[5];
   }
```

Comment: no idea what your asking

Comment: Thnx for reply .. i dont wnt the results of array but the results 3 by 3 ... for example if i have an array of 9 elements .. i want to foreach it 3 times and of every time get 3 element value   .. thnx

Comment: are u still looking for solution?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know what actually you need. As per your comments if you have array with 9 indexes and want to get index 3 by 3, you can use **[`array_chunk():`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)**

**Example**:

```
$yourArr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$result = array_chunk( $yourArr, 3 );
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach($elements as $currentIndex => $element) {
    var_dump($currentIndex); # "number" of element for simple (not assoc) arrays
 }
```

Comment: Thnx for reply .. i dont wnt the results of array but the results 3 by 3 ... for example if i have an array of 9 elements .. i want to foreach it 3 times and of every time get 3 element value